# If $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are non negative real numbers such that $a+b+c+d+e+f=1$, then find maximum value of $ab+bc+cd+de+ef$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$(a+b+c+d+e+f)^2=$ sum of square of each number (X)+ $2($ sum of product of two numbers (Y) $)$
$ab+bc+cd+de+ef \le Y$ since all are positive.

Therefore $1\ge X+(ab+bc+cd+de+ef)$

Edit: From AM GM inequality, $$X\ge 6(abcde)^{1/3}$$and for am-gm inequality for a,b,c,d,e,f: $$1\ge 6(abcdef)^{1/6}$$
Hence $X\ge 6.\frac{1}{36}$ and $X\ge \frac{1}{6}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct, but I don't think it will help you, as you are asked to find the what the maximum is, not just give an upper bound for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$a+b+c+d+e+f=1\implies (a+c+e)(b+d+f)\le \frac14 \\ \implies (ab+bc+cd+de+ef)+(ad+af+cf+be)\le \frac14$$
We can show the first bracket can attain full value by say $a=b=\frac12$.

Comment: How do I know that 1/4 is the maximum value for any a,b,c,d,e,f?

Comment: If $P+Q \le \frac14$ for non-negative $Q$ and $P$ can achieve the value $\frac14$ for some case, then that must be the maximum.  otherwise the inequality is broken...

Comment: The same approach would of course work for more number of variables - you may want to try yourself...

Answer (score 5):

I will give you an example with 4 variables to show how to solve such problems:

$a+b+c+d=1,b=1-(a+c)-d, ab+bc+cd=b(a+c)+cd=(1-(a+c))(a+c)-d(a+c)+cd=(1-(a+c))(a+c)-ad \le \left(\dfrac{(1-(a+c))+(a+c)}{2}\right)^2-ad \le \dfrac{1}{4}$

when $d=0,a+c=\dfrac{1}{2},b=\dfrac{1}{2}$ you will get maximum value.

Comment: any comments for down vote?

Comment: I didn't down vote, and the approach looks good +1. Perhaps the OP is looking for exactly the five variable case to be solved.

Comment: Down voted by accident. I accidentally touched down arrow on my tab. I have up voted your answer.

Comment: @Macavity,thanks. My idea is to let OP goto n case. BTW, Yours looks much more simple.

Comment: @AdityaDev, thanks for your edit and comments. I simply want to improve my answer when I saw down vote. :)