# To find maximum value when sum is fixed

Tags: calculus, inequality

Given that $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$ are six non-negative real numbers such that

$a+b+c+d+e+f=1$.

Find the maximum value of

$ab+bc+cd+de+ef$.

**My Approach**

After lot of thinking I reduced the problem to following:
Given that $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$ are six non-negative real numbers such that

$a+b+c=1$.

Find the maximum value of

$ab+bc$.

which is quite easy to solve:

i.e.  $ab+bc=b(a+c)=b(1-b)=\frac{1}{4}-\left(b-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\leq\frac{1}{4}$.

Not able to extrapolate to the given problem in hand.

Is there a Calculus approach.

Comment: Given the requirements, how do you not get a zero sum for the maximum value as $(n-1)$ values will be zero assuming non-negative integers for a solution?

Comment: Are you sure $a, b, c, d, e$ are integers? If not, check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416397/if-a-b-c-d-e-f-are-non-negative-real-numbers-such-that-abcdef-1-then-f?rq=1

Comment: You are right. It is six non-negative real numbers. I have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Let $0\leq a \leq b \leq c \leq d \leq f \leq e\leq 1$
$$a+b+c+d+f+e=1 \rightarrow (a+b+c+d+f+e-1)^2=0$$ 
$$\rightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+f^2+(e-1)^2+....=0$$
so we have $a^2=b^2=c^2=d^2=f^2=(e-1)^2=0$ i.e., $a=b=c=d=f=0$ and $e=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that $(a,b,c)$ case for a moment. Can you actually get a result that is greater than 0?

$(1,0,0),(0,1,0),$ and $(0,0,1)$ are the only feasible solutions and in each case $ab+bc$ will be 0 which is a lower bound than what you have.