# maximum value of $6$ variable expression.

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c,d,e,f\geq 0$ and $a+b+c+d+e+f=1\;,$ Then $\max(ab+bc+cd+de+ef)$

$\bf{My\;Try::}$ Using Lagrange Multiplier Method::

Let $$F=f(a,b,c,d,e,f) = ab+bc+cd+de+ef-\lambda(a+b+c+d+e+f-1)$$

$$\displaystyle \frac{dF}{da} = b-\lambda\;,\frac{dF}{db} = a+c-\lambda\;,\frac{dF}{dc} = b+d-\lambda\;,\frac{dF}{dd} = c+e-\lambda\;,\frac{dF}{de} = d+f-\lambda$$

and $$\displaystyle \frac{dF}{df} = e-\lambda\;,\frac{dF}{d\lambda} = -(a+b+c+d+e+f-1)$$

Now for $\max\;,$ Put all derivative $=0$

So we get $$a=\lambda\;,b=\lambda\;,c=0\;,d=0\;,e = \lambda\;,f=\lambda$$

Now put into $$a+b+c+d+e+f=1\;,$$ We get $$\lambda = \frac{1}{4}$$

So we get $$\max(ab+bc+cd+de+ef) = \frac{1}{16}$$

But answer given as $\displaystyle = \frac{1}{4}$

plz explain me where I am wrong, Help required, Thanks

Comment: This isn't answering the question, but is a hint to the original problem: what happens to the expression under the transformation $(a, b, c, d, e, f)\to (a+c+e, b+d+f, 0, 0, 0, 0)$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416397/if-a-b-c-d-e-f-are-non-negative-real-numbers-such-that-abcdef-1-then-f?rq=1

Comment: But anyone explain me whats wrong in lagrange multiplier Theorem, Help me , Thanks